# GTK, Glade and Python connecting Handlers from Multiple Classes with the connect_signals

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I hope you are all having a great day!

I can not figure out for the life of me how I can link Multiple Class Handlers to a window object with **connect_signals(obj_or_class)**.  I would like to have both classes **Overview** and **Navigation** injected into the window.  Pondered adding each window and then searching through each class to generate it into a dictionary is viable...but is there an easier way to do it?!

I am OK with python but not the best.  So any direction and explanations and help would be an asset!  Thank you in advance.

```
import os, gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Application():
    def __init__(self):
        self.new_window = Window('overview')
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()
        print('program terminated')

class Window():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.gladefile = os.path.dirname((os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 
            + '/overview/overview.glade')
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(Overview())
        self.window_name =  'overview'
        self.window = self.builder.get_object(self.window_name)
        self.window.show()

class Overview():
    def onDestroy(self, *args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def click(self, button):
        print("clicked")

class Navigation():
    def Overview(self, button):
        # Open the Overview Window
        print("clicked")

    def Settings(self, button):
        # Open the Settings Window
        print("clicked")

    def PID Settings(self, button):
        # Open the PID Settings Window
        print("clicked")

    def Reporting(self, button):
        # Open the Reporting Window
        print("clicked")

# Run Server
if __name__ == '__main__':
main = Application()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you need to connect object's signals with handler separately instead of `Gtk.Builder.connect_signals()`.

Have look at below example.

example.glade

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <interface>
    <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
    <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
      <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      <signal name="destroy" handler="onDestroy" swapped="no"/>
      <child>
        <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
          <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
          <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
          <property name="visible">True</property>
          <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
          <signal name="pressed" handler="onButtonPressed" swapped="no"/>
        </object>
      </child>
    </object>
  </interface>
```

example.py

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Handler:
    @staticmethod
    def onDestroy(*args):
        Gtk.main_quit()

class Handler1:
    @staticmethod
    def onButtonPressed(button):
        print("Hello World!")

builder = Gtk.Builder()
builder.add_from_file("example.glade")
window = builder.get_object("window1")
window.connect("destroy",Handler.onDestroy)
button = builder.get_object("button1")
button.connect("pressed",Handler1.onButtonPressed)
window.show_all()

Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Excellent, this works and you have given me enough to realize that I can connect via Signal Name instead of using a handler class function.  Well played, and this will be useful!  However...I still have to create the associated connecting signal individually for each navigation button where as with the handler class where with the connect_signals...its one class call.

Comment: Is there any way to connect all of these navigation buttons with one separate class call?